# 'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

```
Node version : v8.11.4
npm version: 5.6.0
Commands fired

npm install -g vue-cli
npm install -g vue
vue install wepack test
```

Following error is thrown

'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

When I type `vue -v` also, I am getting the above error

I also added to  windows the path of Vue.js
[image: screenshot 10]

I also noticed that vue.cmd is not coming the following directory
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm

Can anybody please help me to sort the problem

Comment: The `vue` package installs the framework itself (and no CLI). The `vue-cli` package installs the 2.x CLI (an outdated version). You probably meant to install the `@vue/cli` package for the newest 3.x CLI. The [official installation guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) would probably be helpful.

Comment: Note there is no `vue install` command, so `vue install webpack test` would result in a different error once you install `vue-cli` properly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by not running my command terminal as an administrator. I opened my cmder terminal normally by double clicking and it worked.